# K-nearest along ray in large point cloud

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

Are there any well-known data structures known that can handle the following (need to scope whether something is possible):

1. Return the k-closest points to a ray shot through the cloud.
2. Allows quick updates of point locations (basically every point is moved every 500000 queries or so at which point around 500000 old points are removed and the same number added).

In this case the number of points in the cloud will be approximately 3.5 million. The application is in 3D graphics.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem listed in your question, but probably does solve the thing you're trying to *actually* do: signed distance field ray marching.